# SEO rawtext backlink

Tags: seo, googlebot, backlinks

If I add an my http address in a text box of another website and as raw text such that it is not a hyperlink, would this count by googlesbot and for SEO purposes as a backlink?

I note a [question similar](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100051/does-google-count-a-text-only-link-as-a-backlink) to this one has been asked but it's either 5-10 years old and the algo will have evolved or the answer gave no comfort of its accuracy.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think the answer has changed.